# determine swipe lenth to change page in viewpager

Tags: android-viewpager, swipe-gesture

I have a VerticalViewPager in my app that by default user must swipe a long amount finger on screen to change page.

I want to make the app like feedly.

How can i control and customize the amount of swiping to change page that if user swipe his or her finger for example 1cm or bring up the page 10% of screen height, page start changing with animation?

Comment: Attach a custom `onTouchListener` ?

Comment: @Shark how must i do it?

Comment: By attaching a touchListener to the viewpager which will measure how long the user dragged it, compare it to the screen height, and if more than 10% change the page programatically for him. Start measuring in ACTION_DOWN, increment the amount in ACTION_MOVE and stop measuring in ACTION_UP, and then do what must be done.

Comment: thanx a lot brother. you saved me :) @Shark

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't post it as an answer since it's not technically a swipe gesture but it gets the job done.